# Display a table in a JSP that results from a SQL request

Tags: sql, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a JSP page where i have a dropdown list with different cities, and when i choose the city, i would like to display the result of a SQL request, which is a table wit multiple columns.

The dropdown list works fine, but the problem is that i can't display the table in the JSP. i'm getting the error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'idDomaine' {originalText=idDomaine}`

The class Projet, has a many-to one relation with chefprojet and with domaine.

Projet.java

package bean;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Projet implements java.io.Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public int id;
private String libelle;
private String site;
private String finalite;
private String date_actuelle;
private String date_debut;
private String date_previsionnelle;
private Domaine domaine;
private Set <Acteur> assignedActeurs = new HashSet<Acteur>(0);
private Set <Bénéficiaire> assignedBénéficiaires = new HashSet<Bénéficiaire>(0);
private Chefprojet chefprojet;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getLibelle() {
    return libelle;
}
public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
    this.libelle = libelle;
}
public String getSite() {
    return site;
}
public void setSite(String site) {
    this.site = site;
}
public String getFinalite() {
    return finalite;
}
public void setFinalite(String finalite) {
    this.finalite = finalite;
}
public String getDate_actuelle() {
    return date_actuelle;
}
public void setDate_actuelle(String date_actuelle) {
    this.date_actuelle = date_actuelle;
}
public String getDate_debut() {
    return date_debut;
}
public void setDate_debut(String date_debut) {
    this.date_debut = date_debut;
}
public String getDate_previsionnelle() {
    return date_previsionnelle;
}
public void setDate_previsionnelle(String date_previsionnelle) {
    this.date_previsionnelle = date_previsionnelle;
}
public Domaine getDomaine() {
    return domaine;
}
public void setDomaine(Domaine domaine) {
    this.domaine = domaine;
}
public Set<Acteur> getAssignedActeurs() {
    return assignedActeurs;
}
public void setAssignedActeurs(Set<Acteur> assignedActeurs) {
    this.assignedActeurs = assignedActeurs;
}
public Set<Bénéficiaire> getAssignedBénéficiaires() {
    return assignedBénéficiaires;
}
public void setAssignedBénéficiaires(Set<Bénéficiaire> assignedBénéficiaires) {
    this.assignedBénéficiaires = assignedBénéficiaires;
}
public Chefprojet getChefprojet() {
    return chefprojet;
}
public void setChefprojet(Chefprojet chefprojet) {
    this.chefprojet = chefprojet;
}
public Projet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Projet(String libelle, String site, String finalite,
        String date_actuelle, String date_debut,
        String date_previsionnelle, Domaine domaine, Chefprojet chefprojet) {
    super();
    this.libelle = libelle;
    this.site = site;
    this.finalite = finalite;
    this.date_actuelle = date_actuelle;
    this.date_debut = date_debut;
    this.date_previsionnelle = date_previsionnelle;
    this.domaine = domaine;
    this.chefprojet = chefprojet;
}
```

}

Projet.hbm.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 25 avr. 2015 06:50:10 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="bean.Projet" table="PROJET">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="libelle" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LIBELLE" />
        </property>
        <property name="site" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SITE" />
        </property>
        <property name="finalite" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FINALITE" />
        </property>
        <property name="date_actuelle" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATE_ACTUELLE" />
        </property>
        <property name="date_debut" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATE_DEBUT" />
        </property>
        <property name="date_previsionnelle" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATE_PREVISIONNELLE" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="domaine" class="bean.Domaine" fetch="join">
            <column name="IDDOMAINE" />
        </many-to-one>
        <set name="assignedActeurs" table="PROJET_ACTEUR" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many class="bean.Acteur">
            <column name="IDACTEUR" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        <set name="assignedBénéficiaires" table="PROJET_BENEFICIAIRE" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many class="bean.Bénéficiaire">
            <column name="IDBENEFICIAIRE" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>

          <many-to-one name="chefprojet" class="bean.Chefprojet" fetch="join">
          <column name="ID_CHEF"/>
          </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

liste.jsp

```
<%@page import="bean.Projet"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
<%@page import="util.HibernateUtil"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
    String variable = "";
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

    </head>

<%
    List projects = (List) request.getAttribute("listProject");
    if (projects == null)
        projects = new ArrayList();
%>

<body>
<div class="page">
            <div class="header">
                <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="images/Captureocp.PNG" alt=""/></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="acceuil.jsp">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="selected"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                </div>
            </br>
            </br>

    <form method="post" action="liste">
        <p>
            <select name="sites">
                <option value="">-- Choisir --</option>
                <option value="Khouribga">Khouribga</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Casablanca</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Jorf Lasfar</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Benguerir</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Boucraa</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Youssoufia</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Laayoune</option>
                <option value="Casablanca">Safi</option>

            </select><br />

        </p>
        <div class="centre">

        <input type="submit" value="Chercher" name="Chercher"/>
    </div>


                    </br></br></br>

        <table border="1" cellpadding="3pt" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Liste des projets :</td>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                        for (Iterator iterator=projects.iterator();iterator.hasNext();) {

                            Projet projet =(Projet) iterator.next();



                    %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${projet.libelle}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${projet.site}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${projet.finalite}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${projet.date_actuelle}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${projet.date_debut}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${projet.date_previsionnelle}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${projet.domaine.idDomaine}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${projet.chefprojet.id_chef}"/></td>


                    </tr>

                    <%
                        }
                    %>


</table>
    </br></br></br> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

ListeControllerServlet.java

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import util.HibernateUtil;
import dao.ProjetDAO;

public class listeControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);


        try {
            Session session1=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            String selected=request.getParameter("sites");
            session1.beginTransaction();
            Query qry = session1.createQuery("select site,libelle,finalite,date_actuelle,date_debut,date_previsionnelle,idDomaine,id_chef from Projet projet where site='"+selected+"'");
            List list = qry.list();
            request.setAttribute("listProject", list);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("liste.jsp").forward(request, response);
            session1.close(); 

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

I really need your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting `idDomaine` from the entity `Projet`. But this entity doesn't have any `idDomaine` property.

You really, really need to learn how HQL works, and how to use query parameters. Your code is vulenrable to HQL injection attacks.

The query should be

```
List<Projet> list = 
    session1.createQuery("select p from Projet p where p.site = :site")
            .setString("site", selected)
            .list();
```

BTW, you should also learn to use the JSP EL and the JSTL, and to avoid scriptlets. Your JSP is vulerable to XSS attacks.

You should use

```
<c:out value="${projet.site}"/>
```

rather than

```
<%=projet.getSite()%>
```

(and do the same for every property, of course).

Comment: my problem is how to display the valueof idDomaine, and idchefprojet in my jsp. The code doesn't work because i call the Domaine in my jsp and it is an object not a string. And i don't know how to face this problem.

Comment: `<c:out value="${projet.domaine.id}"/>`, which will call `projet.getDomaine().getId()`.

Comment: Thank you! It works with no errors, but still having a little problem, the table i'm getting displayed is empty!

Comment: That probably means that there is no Projet with the selected site. Use your debugger, inspect the value of the site, check your database.

Comment: I checked my database and i have Projet there. The table that i get, is empty but have the number of rows that are equal to the number of Projet for the selected site. So, the request is successful, i just have problem in displaying that.

Comment: And how are you displaying them now?

Comment: No, i mean i still can't displaying them. I'm just displaying the table emty with the number of rows that are exactly equal to the number of Projet for the selected site.

Comment: And how are you displaying them now?

Comment: No, i mean i still can't displaying them. I'm just displaying the table emty with the number of rows that are exactly equal to the number of Projet for the selected site.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me **how** you're **trying** to display the projects. Your table has N rows. So the query retrieves N Projet instances, and your JSP loops over the Projet instances. But each row is empty. So you're not displaying the properties correctly. Hence my question: **how** are you displaying them now?

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't get your question. Can i send you a screen capture of the result?

Comment: No. Post the code showing how you're trying to display the projects.

Comment: The JSP EL doesn't look in local variables. It looks in page/request/session/application attributes. In order to use the JSP EL to display your projects, you'll also have to clean up the rest of the JSP: stop using scriptlets completely. Use the JSTL to loop over the `listProject` attribute: `<c:forEach var="projet" items="${listProject}"> ... </c:forEach>`. Just don't copy and paste code without understanding it. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL.

Comment: I'm sorry i disturbed you. I ll try to learn first about JSTL, thank u for giving me directions. Now i can see things more clearely